# Adding an "Identify Original .csv" column in R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a combined dataset from about 117 other csv files in R-Markdown. I managed to combine them into a single document using the following functions:

```
setwd()
dataFiles <- lapply(Sys.glob("data*.csv", read.csv)
dataFilesCombined <- data.table::rbindlist(datafiles)
```

However, I would like to add a column to the end "dataFilesCombined" that contains information about what original .csv file the data values came from. Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can do this?

I've tried looking for an answer elsewhere on the web, but I can't find anything that would function well with the Sys.glob method.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small reprex using five dataframes, but it should work with 117. Before you combine the dataframes in your list into one big dataframe, you need to assign each dataframe its own identifier that signals which `.csv` file it came from. The easiest way to do this is just use whatever the `.csv` file was called.

```
library(data.table)

# there's a folder called "reprex" in my Documents that contains 
# five dataframes that look like this
testdata <- structure(list(x1 = 3:5, x2 = c(4L, 2L, 5L), x3 = c(1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
testdata
#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  3  4  1
#> 2  4  2  1
#> 3  5  5  2

# make path
path <- "~/Documents/reprex"

# get names of the dataframes, put into character vector
filelist <- list.files(path = path,
                       pattern =" *.csv",
                       full.names = TRUE)

# put all dataframes into a list
lst <- lapply(filelist,
              utils::read.csv,
              header = TRUE,
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# make a name for every dataframe, based on filelist
names(lst) <- filelist
namelist <- fs::path_file(filelist)
namelist <- unlist(lapply(namelist,
                          sub,
                          pattern = ".csv",
                          replacement = ""),
                   use.names = FALSE)
print(namelist)
#> [1] "data1" "data2" "data3" "data4" "data5"

# give every dataframe in the list an ID variable,
# which is actually the original name of the .csv file
lst <- mapply(cbind, lst, "listID" = namelist, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# combine
dataFilesCombined <- data.table::rbindlist(lst)
head(dataFilesCombined)
#>    x1 x2 x3 listID
#> 1:  3  4  1  data1
#> 2:  4  2  1  data1
#> 3:  5  5  2  data1
#> 4:  3  4  1  data2
#> 5:  4  2  1  data2
#> 6:  5  5  2  data2
```